# Use a shell output value in shell script

Tags: shell, sh

If I try following:

```
varReturn=$(ls)
echo $varReturn
```

it shows me the correct output of the listed elements in the directory.

But if I try this one:

```
varReturn=$(/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -n)
echo $varReturn
```

it doesn't show me the expected output :/

**My goal is to check if an HDMI Port is connected or not.**
It' very curious for me, why it works only for some commands.

I'm looking forward to getting some help here. I didn't figure out, what the problem is.

EDIT:

Now I've found another way and tried following:

```
varReturn=`tvservice -s`
echo $varReturn
```

this shows me the correct output:

[image]

But if I use another command, like this one:

```
varReturn=`tvservice -n`
echo $varReturn
```

It shows me no output at echo, but the output from the var (confusing).
[image]

It still shows me the output if I use following code:

```
varReturn=`tvservice -n`
#echo $varReturn
```

The output is shown without the blank space.

Comment: Why not replace `varReturn=$(ls)\necho $varReturn` with `ls`, similalry just use `/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -n` instead of putting it into a variable and echoing the variable.

Comment: just run this command `/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -n` in command prompt manually and see if you get any output?

Comment: yes i get following output: [E] No device present

Comment: execute this command again and just check with $? and let me know.

Comment: It doesn't work with $ I also tried it with quote and double quote. This is damn confusing.

Comment: I also tried `varOutput=$(/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -n)`

Comment: Could it be that the output from the console "[E] No device present" is like blank in my shell script? because if i attach and monitor to the hdmi port it shows me the correct output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least one problem with this code:

```
varReturn=$(/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -n)
echo $varReturn
#    ^ missing double quotes around this variable
```

Adding those quotes will ensure that the variable is passed as a single argument to `echo`. Otherwise, `echo` sees a list of arguments and outputs each one, separated by a space.

The next possible issue is that the command is outputting to standard error, rather than standard output, so it won't be captured by `$()` or the old-fashioned equivalent `` ` ` ``. To correct this, try:

```
output=$(/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -n 2>&1)
#                                 ^ redirect standard error to standard output
echo "$output"
```

Answer (score 1):

When you execute a shell command like `varReturn=$(/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -n)`
 it will store the output to the variable only when the command executed successfully, else it will not hold any information because error/unsuccessful message will be redirected to standard error. Hence you have to redirected it to standard output like below:-

```
varReturn=$(/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -n 2>&1)
```

Now in both successful and unsuccessful execution case output will store in variable `varReturn`.

Comment: I agree that the solution might be to redirect standard error, but it is perfectly reasonable for a program to write to both standard output and standard error, whether or not it exits successfully.

Comment: Yes, I have implemented in some of my shell script which are working fine at the moment. I also faced the same issue what you are facing now. Based on my experience I am wring my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works for me! The same solution as @TomFenech posted.

Comment: Submitted almost at the same time. Thanks anyway :-)